# Is there a clearer way to deal with chained Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, sequelize.js

I'm writing some integration tests around some Sequelize (JS ORM) code. Most Sequelize function calls return Promises, which I haven't worked much with. Is there a clearer way to write the below test case?

```
  it('can add a membership to a user, and user will receive membership.', function() {
return db.Sequelize.Promise.join(

  User.create({ firstName: 'foo', lastName: 'bar',
    identifier: 'foobar', password: 'whatever', }),

  Membership.create( { displayName:'Iron Maiden',role:'somerole' }),

  // This is the part I'd like to improve the clarity of,
  // if possible.
  function(expectedUser, membership) {
    return membership.setUser(expectedUser).then(
      function(updatedMembership) {
        return updatedMembership.getUser().then(
          function(actualUser) {
            return assert.equal(actualUser.id, expectedUser.id);
          })
      })
  })
});
```

Comment: This article really helps with Promises, and deals with your issue: http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function(expectedUser, membership) {
    return membership.setUser(expectedUser)
        .then(function(updatedMembership) {
            return updatedMembership.getUser();
        })
        .then(function(actualUser) {
            return assert.equal(actualUser.id, expectedUser.id);
        });
});
```